Overriding default ListView style with GridView attached
I am in the process of writing a library with extended controls, currently extending ListView and ListViewItem as new controls.
I have come across a problem, when setting GridView in ListView causes that the Style and ControlTemplate I created in ResourcesDictionary are not loaded into the component.
I have tried to find a solution, even rewriting the Style and ControlTemplate like in the following post:
Styling a Listview with a gridview in it
But at the moment I don't have any available solution.
(I will add that if, for example, I insert a ListViewEx control into Window and manually add Style={StaticResource ListViewExStyle} to it, and then add the Style={StaticResource ListViewItemExStyle} style to each ListViewItemEx, everything will work).
Here is my code behind:
public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    /* Here I have a lot of DP and attributes related to appearance extension,
    like BackgroundInactive, BackgroundMouseOver, CornerRadius etc... */
    
    static ListViewEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx)));
    }
    
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new ListViewItemEx();
    }
}

public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    /* Here I have a lot of DP and attributes related to appearance extension,
    like BackgroundInactive, BackgroundMouseOver, CornerRadius etc... */

    static ListViewEx()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx)));
    }
}

And here is what my Themes/ListViewEx.xaml and Themes/Generic.xaml files look like:
ListViewEx.xaml
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx"
  xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx.Data.Theme"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
  <x:Static x:Key="ThemeMgr" Member="theme:ThemeManager.Instance"/>
    
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewEx.ScrollViewerEx.ControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:ScrollViewer}">
    <Border
      x:Name="border"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerBackground}">
            
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              
        <DockPanel
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                
          <ScrollViewer
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            Focusable="False"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                  
            <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter
              AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
              Margin="0"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </ScrollViewer>
          
          <ScrollContentPresenter
            Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
            CanContentScroll="True"
            CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
            CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
        </DockPanel>
        
        <local:ScrollBarEx
          x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
          Cursor="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
          Minimum="0"
          MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarWidth}"
          Style="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarStyle}"
          Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
          ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
          Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
          Width="{TemplateBinding VerticalScrollBarWidth}"/>

        <local:ScrollBarEx
          x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"
          Cursor="Arrow"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Height="{TemplateBinding HorizontalScrollBarHeight}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding HorizontalScrollBarHeight}"
          Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
          Minimum="0"
          Orientation="Horizontal"
          Style="{TemplateBinding HorizontalScrollBarStyle}"
          Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
          ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
          Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
      </Grid>
    </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
  
  <Style x:Key="ListViewEx.ScrollViewerExStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollViewerExStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ScrollViewerEx}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewEx.ScrollViewerEx.ControlTemplate}"/>
  </Style>
  
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewEx.ControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewEx}">
    <Border
      x:Name="Bd"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
      
      <local:ScrollViewerEx Style="{StaticResource ListViewEx.ScrollViewerExStyle}">
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="itemsPresenter"/>
      </local:ScrollViewerEx>
    </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
  
  <Style x:Key="ListViewExStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewExStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewEx}">
    <!-- I don't provide ListViewEx.ColumnHeaderStyle here because it works. -->
    <Setter Property="GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListViewEx.ColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewEx.ControlTemplate}"/>
  </Style>
  
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ListViewEx.ControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewEx}">
    <Border
      x:Name="border"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
      CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

      <GridViewRowPresenter
        x:Name="contentPresenter"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
        TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>

  <Style x:Key="ListViewExStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewEx}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataContext.ThemeBackground, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundInactive" Value="{Binding DataContext.BackgroundInactive, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding DataContext.AccentBorderBrush, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrushInactive" Value="{Binding DataContext.BorderBrushInactive, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DataContext.ThemeForeground, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ForegroundInactive" Value="{Binding DataContext.ForegroundInactive, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ThemeMgr}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ListViewEx.ControlTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

Generic.xaml
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- Other controls. -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx;component/Themes/ListViewEx.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx;component/Themes/ListViewItemEx.xaml"/>
    <!-- Other controls. -->
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewExStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewEx}"/>
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemExStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type local:ListViewItemEx}"/>
  
</ResourceDictionary>


I found a way to get around this.
You simply need to modify the default value of DependencyProperty of View, and add PropertyChangedCallback.
static ListViewEx()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx)));

    ViewProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ListViewEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, ViewPropertyChangedCallback));
}

private static void ViewPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listViewEx = d as ListViewEx;

    if (listViewEx != null && e.NewValue is GridView gridView)
    {
        if (listViewEx.Style == null)
        {
            var mainStyle = GetGenericGridViewExStyle();

            if (mainStyle != null)
                listViewEx.Style = mainStyle;
        }

        if (listViewEx.ItemContainerStyle == null)
        {
            var itemStyle = GetGenericGridViewItemExStyle();

            if (itemStyle != null)
                listViewEx.ItemContainerStyle = itemStyle;
        }


        if (gridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle == null)
        {
            var headerStyle = GetGenericGridViewExColumnHeaderStyle();

            if (headerStyle != null)
                gridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle = headerStyle;
        }
    }
}

protected static Style GetGenericGridViewExStyle()
{
    var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx;component/Themes/GridViewEx.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
    var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri };
    return resourceDictionary["GridViewExStyle"] as Style;
}

protected static Style GetGenericGridViewExColumnHeaderStyle()
{
    var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx;component/Themes/GridViewExColumnHeader.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
    var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri };
    return resourceDictionary["GridViewEx.ColumnHeaderStyle"] as Style;
}

protected static Style GetGenericGridViewItemExStyle()
{
    var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/chkam05.Tools.ControlsEx;component/Themes/GridViewItemEx.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
    var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri };
    return resourceDictionary["GridViewItemExStyle"] as Style;
}

